# Oracle SQL Developer 4 table data tab initial filter

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to setup in Oracle SQL Developer an initial filter for table Data view tab or switch off automatic data load?

I work with a team of analysts whom start analysis by entering that tab and yet keep avoiding manual writing sql. Initial data load last over half minute and pressing cancel on loading dialog with progress bar makes that tab useless.

Just want to make life of these guys bit easier.

Comment: I searched a little and I didn't fount anything useful. [exploring sql developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/exploring-sql-developer-1637307.html)  and [that jeff smith about filtering](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sql-developer-quick-tip-filtering-your-data-grids/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'no' - filters aren't currently persisted across sessions of SQL Developer.

I would suggest Pravin's answer regarding views OR

Create an APEX front end application for data entry for your business users, it's a perfect use-case for APEX.

There is a request on the feature exchange, [check this out](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:7:::NO:RP,7:P7_ID:16241).

Comment: I can't believe they didn't work it out from '09. I'll check out the APEX, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a view on these tables with initial filter ? Instead of table team can query these views. You can limit columns also which team needs.

Comment: Good point but in this case views are too specific and would slow down db which is fine tuned already.

Comment: How does a view slow down a database? It's just a query, like the query being used to bring up your table data.